# Changing header for PHP website

Tags: php, header, web

I am trying to make a website in PHP (I don't really have any experience in this). What I did was use an existing website that somebody created for me and just went about changing things in the .php files.

I had this in header.php:

```
<base href="http://old-domain.com/"; />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css?v=4" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I just changed the 'old-domain' to 'new-domain'.

Now, my homepage of the 'new-domain' looks fine. But all other pages, like new-domain.com/help or new-domain.com/about give me a 404.

On the other hand, when I change the 'new-domain' back to 'old-domain', it displays my old website properly, so I guess this means that the code is alright.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to set up new-domain.com/help, etc somewhere else?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you check `.htaccess` file, It may cause the issue.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? You're blindly changing random elements hoping it'll work. It won't.

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question earlier; must've been deleted. I'm not halucinating, however... 6 months in Morroco will play some mean tricks on the mind. (*cough*)

Comment: How is your website structured? Is there an actual help.php file? If there isn't, then you'll probably need to update your .htaccess file to use the new domain

Comment: Yes, I have all the help.php, about.php, etc files.

Comment: Sidenote: It's `<base href="http://old-domain.com/">` and not `<base href="http://old-domain.com/"; />`

Comment: @user3321684 - Are you sure that the new domain is set up on this server? Have you configured the web server to deal with it?

Comment: Yes, the new domain is set up. The homepage works fine, but other pages like new-domain/something do not.

Comment: Yes, @Fred-ii-, that's how I have it in the code. Something happened when I pasted it here lol.

Comment: @user3321684 - I'm going to assume that there's something in the server configuration that needs changing. Simplying altering one PHP file won't generate 404 errors in other files, so I think it's a configuration issue.

Comment: @andrewsi Any idea where I should look? I've spent a lot of time, going through all the files. I have about.php set up as before (working fine with the old domain). And I have header.php (again, working fine with the old domain). I JUST changed the base href to the new domain.

Comment: @user3321684 - I'd check the configuration for the server, and check the document root for the new website. Generally different sites will be set up in different directories - when you're clicking on the link to go to help.php, it'll be taking you to the new site and looking for the file under its document root.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether any other file contains the link www.old-domain.com and change it to www.new-domain.com.
I assume the project structure is the same.

Comment: I've checked, I don't see any other instance of the old-domain.

Answer (score 0):

because there is no seperate php file for those pages create seperate file for each like help.php and about.php and then include those in header

Comment: I have the help.php etc files already. It's just when I change it to the new-domain, it failed. Old-domain works fine!

Comment: in that old domain they had use some server address and password it wont match with any other if you want to try try it in localhost